# file upload / mkdir() problems

Tags: php, file, file-upload, upload, mkdir

I'm trying to create a fairly simple (in theory) file upload 'process'. I've trawled through the site and, although there are snippets of what I need, nothing seems to work!

Basically, I am trying to create a function that processes as below:

1. Get file extension
2. Get file name
3. Combine file name, clientID and extension
4. Check that the target directory exists. If not, create it.
5. Move the file(under the new name) into the directory

My file structure is as follows:

- Root

  - admin

    - uploads

      - client_uploads

        - $clientID

Here's what I have:

```
 <?php
 include("dbconnect.php");

 error_reporting(-1); // ALL messages and 
 ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

 if($_GET['clientID']){

 //This function separates the extension from the rest of the file name and returns it 
 function findexts ($filename) 
 { 
 $filename = strtolower($filename) ; 
 $exts = split("[/\\.]", $filename) ; 
 $n = count($exts)-1; 
 $exts = $exts[$n]; 
 return $exts; 
 } 

 //Get filename function
 $filename = "test"; //I dont know how to create this function at the moment
 return $filename;

 //This applies the function to our file  
 $ext = findexts ($_FILES['uploaded']['name']) ; 

 // we will be using the clientID as the new folder and adding it into the filename
 $clientID = mysql_real_escape_string((int)$_GET['clientID']);

 //merge filename
 $filename2 = $filename."_".$clientID.".";

 //Scan for existing directory
 $folder = '../admin/uploads/client_uploads/'.$username.'/';
 if (is_dir("$folder") == false) {
 mkdir("$folder", 0777);    
 echo "Directory created";
 } 


 //This assigns the subdirectory you want to save into... make sure it exists!
 $target = "admin/client_uploads/$clientID";

 //This combines the directory, the random file name, and the extension
 $target = $target . $filename2.$ext; 

 //Move file under new name 

 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name'], $target)) 
 {
 echo "The file has been uploaded as ".$filename2.$ext;
 } 
 else
 {
 echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";
 }
}
?>
```

I'm not getting any error messages (although I've explicitly asked for them) and I just end up with a blank screen. Folder is not created anywhere on my server and nothing happens.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked PHP's error logs for messages? Have you tried to debug step by step by commenting out sections and `var_dump`ing individual variables?

Comment: I dont know how to check my error logs - I would have thought any errors would have been displayed on the page as per my first lines of code?

Comment: Seems to be an error with the 'split' command too - something about it being depreciated. Do I need to use an 'explode' cammond or something in it's place?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one,

```
<?php
//get file name in your own way 
$filename   =   $_FILES["filename"]["name"];
$fLength    =   strlen($filename);
$exParts    =   explode(".",$filename);
$totalParts =   count($exParts);
$extension  =   $exParts[$totalParts-1];
$eLength    =   strlen($extension);
$filename   =   substr($filename,0,($fLength-$eLength+1));
//Get the client ID as you need
$client_ID  =   //client ID here;
$up_file_name   =   $filename."_".$client_ID.".".$extension;
$folder     = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/admin/uploads/client_uploads/".$username."/";

if(!is_dir($folder))
{
//Create directory
$parts  = explode("/",$folder);
for($j=0; $j<count($parts); $j++)
{
$fpath    = "";
for($k=0; $k<=$j; $k++)
{
$fpath  .=  $parts[$k]."/";
}
if(!is_dir($fpath))
{
$oldmask=umask(0);
mkdir($fpath,0755);
umask($oldmask);
}
}
}
//Upload your file
$pathtoupload   =   $folder.$up_file_name;
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["filename"]["tmp_name"],$pathtoupload))
{
echo "Uploaded successfully";
}
else
{
echo "Can't upload";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use used $folder with in doublequotes. Remove that and use

```
 //Scan for existing directory
 $folder = '../admin/uploads/client_uploads/'.$username.'/';
 if (is_dir($folder) == false) {
 mkdir($folder, 0777);    
 echo "Directory created";
 }
```

Comment: Tried this, still nothing at all. Even changed the variable $username to $clientID as per my code above.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must set the writing permissions in the server...And it is need to create the directories one by one...try this....

```
$parts  = explode("/",$folder);
for($j=0; $j<count($parts); $j++)
{
  $fpath    = "";
  for($k=0; $k<=$j; $k++)
  {
    $fpath  .=  $parts[$k]."/";
  }
  if(!is_dir($fpath))
  {
    $oldmask=umask(0);
    mkdir($fpath,0755);
    umask($oldmask);
  }
}
```

Comment: Again, nothing returned. No directory created. No response at all. Surely it cant be this hard to create such a simple function....can it?